# MySQL SELECT DISTINCT to include duplicates

Tags: mysql

I have a query, such as the one below.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`name`) FROM `mydb`
WHERE `name` IN ('a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e');
```

I am providing the list of letters above and querying my database.

What I want is for it to return rows including the duplicates (so rows that have a name of 'a', two 'b' rows, 'c', two 'd' rows, and 'e').

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

CURRENT Output:

```
+------+
| name |
+------+
| a    |
| b    |
| c    |
| d    |
| e    |
+------+
```

DESIRED Output:

```
+------+
| name |
+------+
| a    |
| b    |
| b    |
| c    |
| d    |
| d    |
| e    |
+------+
```

I cannot remove distinct. I should have provided more background. Each entry in the table has the potential to have another row with a duplicate name in it.

The reason why I need distinct is because I don't want 30 rows for the name 'a'. I just want one row for each entry that I input into the query.

Comment: include your output in your question .

Comment: Don't use `DISTINCT`. Just `SELECT name ...`

Comment: I edited my question to explain why I can't remove `DISTINCT` from my query.

Comment: Looks like you have to write your own storage procedure, where you will group and count your arguments, and then make query with union and LIMIT X, where X - quantity of the same arguments ('b', 'b', 'b') - LIMIT 3. I don't see other way to do that

Comment: @FSou1 Whoa. I can look into that to see if it might be a solution to my problem. I have never dealt with that or even heard of it really.

Comment: `DISTINCT` doesn't care about the number of occurences of name in the `IN` clause. It's job is to have one raw per each unique name

Comment: Solve it at the application level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `union all` like this:

```
select distinct name from t1 where name in ('a','c','e')
Union all
select distinct name from t1 where name in ('a')
order by name;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f28d8/4/0)

**EDITED**

Put all the distinct rows togather in one single condition and add any other duplicate row you need.

Comment: This is good. I think it gives me what I want. Is there any way to make it.. Nicer? My example was obviously pretty simple, but the reason it's the way it is is so I don't have to do between 10 and 50 queries. Almost all my `name`'s I am querying for are different. This is to address a pretty fringe case for me.

Comment: As you could see in start post, 'I just want one row for each entry that I input into the query'.

Comment: @FSou1 check the `DESIRED Output`

Comment: Done, what i miss? TS pass two arguments 'b' and two arguments 'd'- that's because he got two rows, but other have only 1 row per argument. Am i wrong?

Comment: @FSou1 I want exactly one row per argument, even if there is duplicate arguments.

Comment: @MiloGertjejansen what is the problem in my query now?

Comment: @7alhashmi No, I think this one is good. I am just trying to test it with my code (need to build the actual query string to use). So I am going to accept the answer some time tomorrow. In quick tests in phpmyadmin it worked well though.

Answer (score 1):

Is the word `DISTINCT` a give away. Just remove it!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT `name` FROM `mydb`
WHERE `name` IN ('a', 'b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'd', 'e');
```

Answer (score 0):

The DISTINCT keyword tells mysql to not show any duplicate rows. Just use your query without distinct.